# Rust Crate: Defining configurable variables

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

If there are certain configurable values in a crate, can they be exposed in some way through a Rust crate?

Like we expose boolean features (yes/no) through it, I would like to expose certain values, say, wait_time (which is an integer) and such.

Answer (score 0):

One typical way would be with environment variables. Check out `eng_logger`'s use of the `RUST_LOG` variable, and `rayon`'s use of `RAYON_NUM_THREADS` as some common examples:

https://docs.rs/env_logger/0.9.0/env_logger/

https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.1/rayon/index.html

Alternatively, depending on the API you expose to other crates, you might be able to configure it via a typical method call. For example, if your crate has to be "initialized" with a call to some `init()` function, perhaps that function could take some data as configuration. Perhaps you're passing a configuration struct into function calls already and it could be configured there?

Comment: That is an option, but I was thinking more from the perspective of 'const' that can be used at compile time itself, rather than having to define them when the module is used.

Comment: You can use environment variables at compile time with `env!`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.env.html. Feels less idiomatic though :/ Perhaps consumers could implement a trait with an associated constant? Unfortunately, AFAIK, there's nothing like cargo features for arbitrary data